# GCP access snapshots of one account from another account to create VM instace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I have two snapshots on my account1 which I would like to access and create VM instances from account2. I added my account2 as Cloud Storage Admin to IAM in my account1 and vice versa, still I cannot see snapshots of account1 on my account2. I was able to do this few months back, however I am not able to do this anymore, is anything changed at GCP or am I missing anything here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps that worked for me:

```
(project1)$ gcloud compute snapshots list
Listed 0 items.
(project2)$ gcloud compute snapshots list
NAME        DISK_SIZE_GB  SRC_DISK                        STATUS
snapshot-1  30            us-central1-a/disks/instance-1  READY
```

I added the user who owns project1 to project2 and granted the role: [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects#share)

> Snapshots: Select Compute Engine > Compute Storage Admin from the role
>   selector.

Then I checked for the snapshots in project1 and was able to find the snapshot from project2:

```
(project1) gcloud compute snapshots  list --project project2
NAME        DISK_SIZE_GB  SRC_DISK                        STATUS
snapshot-1  30            us-central1-a/disks/instance-1  READY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can share access to images and snapshots with other users by granting them the following IAM roles or permissions at the resource, project, folder, or organization level.

Images: The **roles/compute.imageUser** role or the **compute.images.useReadOnly** permission.

Snapshots: The **roles/compute.storageAdmin** role or the **compute.snapshots.useReadOnly** permission.

I think you have given role as **storage admin**, instead give **compute.storageAdmin.**